# FlatList is not get rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to convert regular mapped Array inside scrollview into a `FlatList` component without much luck. Using map worked great but now converting the same data into `FlatList` doesnt render anything.

FLATLIST:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList 
     keyExtractor={(item) => item.url}
     data={this.props.links}
     renderItem={
       ({item}) => {
         <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => Browser.open(`https://${link.mobile.replace('https://', '')}`)}>
            <LinkContainer
               id={item.id}
               likes={item.totalLikes}
               username={this.props.username}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      }
    }
   />
</View>
```

MAPPED ARRAY:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  this.props.links((link) => {

    return(

         <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => Browser.open(`https://${link.mobile.replace('https://', '')}`)}>
            <LinkContainer
               id={link.id}
               likes={link.totalLikes}
               username={this.props.username}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>

    )

})
```

so the example using the `map` methid working great but then trying to convert it to flatlist is failing without any logs or error, just blank page

Comment: Can you create expo snack ? Or specify `link` array format

Comment: format: `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` and each object: `
`{likes: Array(1), dislikes: Array(0), _id: "", username: "", id: "https://...", …}`

Comment: updated answer please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per information you provided it seems like you missing **spreading** arguments in `renderItem` function.
We used `{}` so need to return JSX tag

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList 
     keyExtractor={(link) => link.url}
     data={this.props.links}
     renderItem={
      ({item}) => {  // Here you receive array element as item. 
        return <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => Browser.open(`https://${item.mobile.replace('https://', '')}`)}>
            <LinkContainer
               id={item.id}
               likes={item.totalLikes}
               username={this.props.username}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      }
    }
   />
</View>
```

Have look at [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem) what you receive in `renderItem`

Comment: you mean to wrap the arg in {} ? I tried it this return an error that says it cant find the props X on undefined where the arg I wrapped is the undefined

Comment: Can you please try now. you need specify exact name which item in this case

Comment: I updated the code example for you to see what have I tried. But it stiil doesnt work

Comment: previously component not `returned`

Comment: sorry I didnt saw the `return` statement you wrote. I added it and it worked great thanks(:

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be quite simple. Your `<Flatlist>` which is inside `<View style={styles.container}>` doesn't have height and width of its own so the items that are rendered inside it are also without height and width and thus won't appear on the screen. (If you used flex to set height inside the `LinkContainer` component).
Give your `Flatlist` a height and a width and then try again.

Also, as per Revansiddh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51019469/7641174) your `renderItem` prop should look like this.

Notice the removal of `{}` in the fat arrow function. If you wrap JSX inside `{}` as in your question the fat arrow function won't return anything or would return `undefined` and thus nothing will get rendered on the screen. So you need a return statement or the removal of `{}` altogether.

```
({ item }) => (
         <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => Browser.open(`https://${item.mobile.replace('https://', '')}`)}>
            <LinkContainer
               id={item.id}
               likes={item.totalLikes}
               username={this.props.username}
            />
         </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Comment: thanks @Revansiddh answer was actually good I just forgot the `return` statement, I added it and it works ! thanks (:

Comment: No problem mate! :)